# QEMU/KVM fails to start on openSUSE

Tags: linux, virtualization, opensuse

I've gotten this to run before. I'm using the OVMF BIOS image and the EFI executables generated using [this](https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:UEFI_Secure_boot_using_qemu-kvm) guide. I ran `sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -bios /usr/share/qemu-ovmf/bios/bios.bin -hda fat:/home/main/Documents/EFI_HD/` which ends up exiting with:

```
Warning: default MAC address being used, creating potential for address conflict
vvfat: /home/main/Documents/EFI_HD/ chs 1024,16,63
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(qemu-system-x86_64:2549): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display
```

What might be causing this?

Comment: Do you have a graphical display?  Are you running this remotely like over an ssh session or something like that?

Comment: @EricRenouf I have a graphical display. I'm using an install of openSUSE that is standard and pretty new. Like I said, this was working before? SSH is not being used that I know of (maybe it runs behind the scenes, but I don't know how QEMU works).

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` seems to be the problem here.  Using that you run the command as root, but root doesn't necessarily have access to your window manager.  If you run `xhost +` before trying to open the VM that should let root open the window that Qemu is trying to open.

Alternately, you could tell qemu to use a VNC server instead (add `-vnc :<port>` like `-vnc :1` to have it listen on all interfaces to port 5901 for VNC clients or `-vnc localhost:1` to listen on just localhost).  Then you could use `vncviewer` or `vinagre` or some other VNC viewer to connect to `localhost:1`

Or you could, apparently, use `xdg-su -c "<qemu command"`, though I've never used that myself.  It was offered as a solution [here](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/405624-sudo-doesnt-open-X-programs) to a very similar problem.

And for what it's worth, qemu does not generally use ssh as part of it's startup.

Comment: Neither of those work. Both xhost+xhost + and sudoxhost+sudo xhost + returned xhost:unab≤→opendisplayxhost: unable to open display "". xdg−suxdg-su returned kdesu:ca∩otco∩ect→XserverIP:0.0kdesu: cannot connect to X server IP:0.0 ("localhost" coming from $DISPLAY$DISPLAY, which I had read to IP:0.0IP:0.0 somewhere else). I want to know what changed to make it not work.

Comment: @Melab are you able to open any graphical things from the terminal where you're trying to run these things?  Like if you have `xeyes` or `xclock` or something like that installed can you open any of those before doing the `sudo`?

Comment: `xdg-su -c "<qemu command"` worked for me. +1 for that.